# French street language in mugging situation

Tags: safety, french-language

I am travelling to a less than safe area near Paris (for reasons outside of my influence). While I dont expect to get mugged I would like to be not fully unprepared. My French is at a low-level maybe A2. So while my strategy is to fully comply in a mugging situation, I would like to know what phrases I have to expect, so that I actually can comply.

What are common phrases used when getting mugged?

Comment: I'm confused on this one. There are special phrases in this situation? Is it not just usually give me your wallet or I shall use this knife?

Comment: @theotherone how to say 'give me your wallet or I shall use this knife' (in French, preferably also French slang)

Comment: But do you even need to know the phrases? Surely if someone grabs you and starts waving a knife around, you already know that whatever they're saying is basically "give me your money or I'll stab you".

Comment: @ChrisH ok, lets drop the knife. According to reports a lot of ppl approach one for begging in groups in this area. So I need to distinguish this from a lot of ppl approaching and threatinging to beat one up (in order to get money).

Comment: I'm struggling to imagine how those two groups would be ambiguous, regardless of whether you understand the words they're saying. Muggings don't tend to involve a whole lot of subtlety, the fact you're being overtly threatened is the whole idea.

Comment: @ChrisH DId you ever get approached by aggresive beggars? This is not mugging but it is a fine line, and the distinction is if they announce violence. Aggressive begging: you continue to go and push through. Threat of violence: you hand over the money.

Comment: I've been *approached*. I've never been unclear about whether or not they were threatening me with violence... But if that's your concern go ahead and use your A2 "je ne parle pas francais" and I'm sure they can find a non-verbal way to make it clear they're threatening you with violence, if that's their intention.

Comment: @ChrisH well, lets agree to disagree then.

Comment: @lalala You could try a swift 'disons qu'on n'est pas d'accord' (let's agree to disagree) as a response to the muggers, keep on walking without handing over any money, and see if they agree with you to disagree.

Answer (score 6):

I got mugged when living in France. The phrase I remember them using during that experience was "vide les poches" (empty your pockets).

However, I'd agree with the comments on the original question, the fact that someone is trying to mug you should be apparent regardless of your competence in the language. Beggars will be persistent, sure, but it's very different to an actual "aggression".